# rsync --remove-source-files but only those that match a pattern

Tags: command-line, rsync

Is this possible with rsync?

Transfer everything from `src:path/to/dir` to `dest:/path/to/other/dir` and delete *some* of the source files in `src:path/to/dir` that match a pattern (or size limit) but keep all other files. I couldn't find a way to limit `--remove-source-files` with a regexp or size limit.

*Update1 (clarification):* I'd like all files in `src:path/to/dir` to be copied to `dest:/path/to/other/dir`. Once this is done, I'd like to have some files (those that match a regexp or size limit) in `src:path/to/dir` deleted but don't want to have anything deleted in `dest:/path/to/other/dir`.

*Update2 (more clarification):* Unfortunately, I can't simply rsync everything and then manually delete the files matching my regexp from src:. The files to be deleted are continuously created.

So let's say there are N files of the type I'd like to delete after the transfer in src: when rsync starts. By the time rsync finishes there will be N+M such files there. If I now delete them manually, I'll lose the M files that were created while rsync was running.

Hence I'd like to have a solution that guarantees that the only files deleted from src: are those known to be successfully copied over to dest:.  I could fetch a file list from dest: after the rsync is complete, and compare that list of files with what I have in src:, and then do the removal manually.  But I was wondering if rsync can do this by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete before the transfer or after?  That is, should dest: have the deleted files?

I suspect that the easiest way is to do these as separate commands.  Use `find | xargs rm` to delete the desired files (maybe adding an `egrep` to the pipe if the regex is complex) and `rsync` to do the copy.  The order of execution will be determined by the answer to my question in the first paragraph.

Comment: I'd like to them deleted after the transfer, because I'd like to have the files on dest:

Comment: The problem with "find | xargs rm" or some such is that the content of src: keeps growing, i.e. files are being created continuously. When I start the rsync let's say there are X files, by the time rsync finishes there are X+n files and only the first X files are copied. If I would manually delete files from src: at this point, the n files that were created while rsync was running would be lost on src: without being archived on dest:

Comment: Look up the -mtime option to find.  You can select for removal only those files that were modified before you started the rsync

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the "proper" way to do what you want is via find with a function - this lets you do this in an "almost-atomic" way.

I also recommend using mtime - this prevents it from doing files that are still being written to - though there are likely other better ways to avoid that as well.

Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/executing-user-defined-function-in-a-find-exec-call for related ways to export functions. The example below is bash-specific:

```
pattern='^match\.this\.pattern.*only$'

rsync_rm() {
 rsync path/to/dir/$1 dest:/path/to/other/dir/.
 echo $1 | egrep $pattern > /dev/null && rm $1
}

export -f rsync_rm

find path/to/dir -mtime +1 -exec bash -c 'rsync_rm "$@"' bash {} +
```